# SonarQube - authors_by_line Metric

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

In Sonar version 3.6.x the Plugin "SCM Activity http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin" provided a metric "authors_by_line". So it was possible to get resources with authors e.g. .../api/resources?resource=foo&metrics=authors_by_line.

But in SonarQube version 4.0 and 4.1 it seems not possible to get these information.
Is there a known bug or is this metric deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get resources recursive over an project, then you must define the parameter depth=-1 e.g. .../api/resources?resource=foo&depth=-1&metrics=authors_by_line .
Then the output contains authors_by_line.